# Radio button in Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I've created sort of radio button chooser table with check boxes so I can pick which line I want and that brings the value from this line out to the result cell...

this is the basic principle:

[image]

this way which ever checkbox I click, the value of that cell becomes 1 (TRUE) rather than 0 (FALSE), and using `SUMPRODUCT` formula, every line is multiplied by the boolean checkbox so if the checkbox is not checked, the production is zeroed, and if the checkbox is checked, the value remains.

In this example on B8 I get:

`B8 = A2*B2 + A3*B3 + A4*B4 = 0*3 + 1*8 + 0*12 = 8`

That works well as long as the values are numbers..

**Now I'm trying to do the same but with string values..**

something like this:

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Use `IF` to get corresponding Col B
- JOIN the resulting array

#### Sample:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(A2:A4,B2:B4,)))
```

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",",IF(A2:A4,B2:B4,)))` leaves commas in the cell. Perhaps an empty string would be the ideal solution `=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("",IF(A2:A4,B2:B4,)))` ?

Answer (score 2):

I used the checkbox and Google Apps Script, where column A (1) and column B (2) contain the checkboxes. For example:

[image: Column A and Column B checkboxes]

```
function onEdit(evt) {

    var range = evt.range;
    var val = range.getValue();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var col = range.getColumn();

    // -------------------------------------
    // --- Cannot be both add and delete ---
    // -------------------------------------
    if (col == 1) {
        if (val) {
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2).setValue('FALSE'); 
        }
    }
    else if (col == 2) {
        if (val) {
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue('FALSE'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my codes. Please run onStart() for setting up radio boxes as well.

```js
function onEdit(e) {

  // radio button
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var gsheetrange = gsheet.getDataRange().getValues();  
  var rowcount = gsheetrange.length; // find end of row

  for(var i = 0; i <= rowcount; i++) { // start from 0. 
      if (i==gedited){
      gsheet.getRange(gedited, 2).setValue("true"); 
   }
   else
   {
    gsheet.getRange(i, 2).setValue("false"); 
   }
  }
}
```